# Yii2 Как правильно сделать запрос, что бы подсчитать рейтинг

Tags: yii2

Всем привет не могу сделать правильный запрос в таблицу что бы подсчитать общие количество рейтинга.

Поля таблицы

```
id | performer_id | review | rateNum
```

Сам запрос, нужно подсчитать в колонке rateNum

```
        $countReviews = OrdersHasReviewsRating::find()
        ->asArray()
        ->where(['performer_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант

```
$sql = 'SELECT SUM(`rateNum`) as `sum` FROM `' . 
OrdersHasReviewsRating::tableName() . '` WHERE 
`performer_id`=:performer_id';
$ratingSummary = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)
->bindValue(':performer_id', Yii::$app->user->id)
->queryScalar(); // или ->queryOne();
```

Второй вариант

```
$countPerformerRating = OrdersHasReviewsRating::find()
->where(['performer_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
->sum('rateNum');
```